# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web won't start. "Cannot find one or more components"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-express

I installed VS Express 2012 for Web from the Web Platform Installer, but it won't start.  I click the shortcut (or the EXE) and get this error message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web
>
> Cannot find one or more components.  Please reinstall the application.

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, running the repair tool. Downloading the standalone install, etc.  I have Windows 7 x64 SP1 fully updated from Windows Update.  I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting.  I ran collect.exe but don't know where to look or what to look for.

Comment: This doesn't really count as an answer, but I ended up wiping this machine for a fresh install of Windows 8.  Problem solved, for me anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS 2012 Express for Desktop, also on Windows 7 x64 SP1. These two links have the same solution which worked for me:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f24be62-7a19-4f95-bc33-1f57cc3d3fcd/visual-studio-express-2012-for-desktop-cannot-find-one-or-more-components?forum=vssetup

http://maditguy72.blogspot.com/2013/06/cannot-find-one-or-more-components.html

The solution that worked for me is to delete this registry key: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]`